# Is it possible to resend SMS_RECEIVED broadcast?

Tags: android, sms, broadcast

I want to resend received SMS_RECEIVED broadcast. I've find example here: http://blog.dev001.net/post/14085892020/android-generate-incoming-sms-from-within-your-app and make it by analogy:

```
boolean received=false;

private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
            if(!received) {

                received=true;

                Bundle pudsBundle = intent.getExtras();
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) pudsBundle.get("pdus");
                SmsMessage messages =SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);

                abortBroadcast();

                if(/*my condition here*/) {
                    Intent update = new Intent();
                    update.setClassName( "com.android.mms", "com.android.mms.transaction.SmsReceiverService");
                    update.setAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
                    update.putExtra( "pdus" , new Object[] { pdus });
                    startService(update);
                }

            }
        }
    }
};
```

But this code crash com.android.mms (I see "I/ActivityManager(71): Process com.android.mms (pid 904) has died." in LogCat) with this:

```
threadid=8: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
FATAL EXCEPTION: SmsReceiverService
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object;
    at android.provider.Telephony$Sms$Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(Telephony.java:617)
    at com.android.mms.transaction.SmsReceiverService.handleSmsReceived(SmsReceiverService.java:299)
    at com.android.mms.transaction.SmsReceiverService.access$100(SmsReceiverService.java:67)
    at com.android.mms.transaction.SmsReceiverService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(SmsReceiverService.java:172)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the same data( same received sms) it would be better to reuse the same intent and don't tray to build your own. just use  intent.putExtras(Bundle extras); 
Can you replace "update.putExtra( "pdus" , new Object[] { pdus });" with 
"update.putExtra(pudsBundle)". Try it and let me know if it works, i haven't time to reproduce.